# Publishing container port in Docker before the server process has started

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've been trying to figure out why some JUnit tests that pass for me locally, fail when run inside a dockerised Jenkins slave.

To do this, I've spun up a Jenkins slave in a docker container and published port 5005 from the container, as evidenced by the output of the command below.

```
diveshp@diveshp-Virtual-Machine:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
562efdc6cdbb        docker.artifactory.abc.com.au/jenkins-slave-vita:11.1   "jenkins-slave -work…"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp   jenkins-slave-local
```

The catch is that there isn't any process in the container that is listening on port 5005 (yet).

I then sshed into the container and tried to debug a few maven tests using

`mvn clean test -Dmaven.surefire.debug`

Sure enough, I see the message

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

But now, I can't attach a debugger to this port from my IDE (using localhost:5005).

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Using `docker exec` that way doesn't seem right.  I'd debug why the Jenkins slave isn't starting up, and submit a normal Jenkins job to do builds and run tests.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry, I think I might have described my problem incorrectly. The slave starts up just fine. I was trying to debug why some tests were failing on the slave. I sshed into the slave and tried to run the the tests in debug mode so that I could attach a debugger and find the cause for the failures.